# Binomial as sum of Bernoulli

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

It is a well known fact that if $$Y_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$$ then $$X=\sum_{I=1}^n Y_i$$ is $Binomial(n,p)$.One can prove this using moment generating functions pretty easily.

My question is how can I show this using the measure theory definition of a random variable. That is, considering an rv as a function from $\Omega$ to R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr A, P)$ be our probability space, let $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B)$ be the reals together with the Borel sigma-algebra.

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n: (\Omega, \mathscr A) \rightarrow (\mathbb R, \mathscr B)$ be independent $Bernoulli(p)$ variables. Then 
$$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R,\, \omega \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(\omega)$$ is a random variable $(\Omega, \mathscr A) \rightarrow (\mathbb R, \mathscr B)$ (recall that sums of measurable functions are again measurable).

For $k=0,\ldots,n$, it holds that $P(X=k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. This is because $X=k$ iff there are exactly $k$ of the $Y_i$ equal to $1$. This means that $X$ has a Binomial distribution.

If you want to write down the probability measure that $X$ induces on $\mathscr B$, then you can write it as 
$$P_X = P \circ X^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\epsilon_k ,$$ where $\epsilon_k$ is point mass in $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notations, for $k \in [|1,n|]$,
$$ P(X=k) = P(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i= k)$$

Then, there must be $k$ Bernoulli variables must be equal to 1. You choose $k$ from the $n$ available. The others are equal to $0$.

Finally,

$$ P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Thus, $X$ follows a binomial law.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A couple things 

1) Strictly speaking, I don't think you can use convergence in probability to show convergence in distribution, you need to use MGFs or CDFs for that

2)I'm looking for the strict measure theory answer

Comment: @1524 Thank you for the correction.

Comment: is what I said true? I don't think you can technically say the first equation you can only say $$P(X \leq k) = P( \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \leq k)$$ or no?

Comment: @user2879934 The first equation is true as a Bernoulli variable has its value in $\{0, 1\}$. For the sum to be equal to $k$, you will need $k$ of them to be equal to $1$/

Comment: But, my point is that if a random variable is a function of another (in this case a sum of i.i.d RVS) then you cannot directly say that the probability of that RV is the function, you have to account for the transformation to preserve volume...i.e. you have to calculate the jacobian, like in Casella and Berger chapter 2... the only reason I think that might not apply here is that we are dealing with PMFs not PDFs

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Omega=\{0,1\}^n$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(\Omega)$ and probability $P$ determined by: $$P(\{\omega\})=p^{\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i}q^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i}$$

Then the $Y_i:\omega\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\omega\mapsto\omega_i$ have Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ and are independent.

And $X:=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ has binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and $n$.

Comment: Awesome, but how do you go from the probability measure you have up there to the classic binomial one?

Comment: By counting I would say. ${X=k}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i=k\}$. This set has $\binom{n}{k}$ elements and for each of these $\omega$'s we have $P(\{\omega\})=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. That results in $P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the set-theoretic equality

$$\left\{X = k\right\} = \bigcup_{J \subset  \left\{1 , \ldots  , n\right\}, |J|=k} \left(\bigcap_{j \in  J} \left\{{Y}_{j} = 1\right\} \cap  \bigcap_{j \notin  J} \left\{{Y}_{j} = 0\right\}\right)$$

Note that this is a disjoint union and the intersected events are independent, which proves the binomial law.

No hypothesis is needed on the probability space $\Omega$. The key argument is that there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of cardinality $k$
in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Okay I like this, so if you take the probability of the RHS, by additivity, this becomes the regular definition of the binomial?

Comment: Exactly it is the sum of $\binom{n}{k}$ times the quantity $p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Comment: You still need that $Y_i : \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ right?

Comment: Of course, it is the definition of a Bernouilli variable. I'm using the fact that a sum of $n$ terms all equal to $0$ or $1$ is equal to $k$ if $k$ terms are equal to $1$ and $n-k$ terms are equal to $0$. $X(\omega) = \sum_i Y_i(\omega)$.